# The Broken Device

Tags: password

Your old friend from college is visiting and brings back this weird electronic machine with him. **He says that it's supposed to take input and spit out a number**, but some prank was pulled on him (he was kind of a geek) where he, and the device, got dunked into the pool. It was turned on and your friend was electrocuted. Luckily he did survive (he did visit didn't he?) but during that *shocking* moment he forgot how his device worked, and the device was broken.

He came to you hoping you could help, he was hoping you could remember how it had worked. After you reply "no", he still wants help. He says you're the smartest person he knows.

***Since it's broken the only information you have is a video you guys had took in college, and a weird note that had slowly been disappearing over the years.***

In the video you guys were testing it. The few examples you could make out were:

> $1863784 \rightarrow 1$
>   $1243242 \rightarrow 9$
>   $1742 \rightarrow 5$

The note seemed to be a set of instructions the computer followed:

> Stp1
>   adalheumrs
>   Sp2
>   rpatstputloetsnledgt
>   Sep3
>   rurnvle

Your friend was a terrible writer back then and his words were packed tightly together, therefore you couldn't distinguish any spaces. It was written in English.

Your friend needs your help to figure out how it works, and what the note says.

**Just to clarify, you can do it in either order. Figuring out how it gets the number can be figured out easily by figuring out the note, or you could reverse the order and try to use the numbers to help figure out the note.**

Comment: Step 1: Add all her(mitian?) numbers maybe? step 2: Repeat step until ....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1 says:

```
adalheumrs
```

> **ad**d **al**l t**he** n**um**be**rs**

Step 2 says:

```
rpatstputloetsnledgt
```

> **r**e**p**e**at** **st**e**p** 1 **u**n**t**i**l** y**o**u g**et** a **s**i**n**g**le** **d**i**g**i**t**

Step 3 says:

```
rurnvle
```

> **r**et**urn** **v**a**l**u**e**

Basically, the machine keeps summing up the digits until you get a one-digit number, and returns that number. Like so:

> $1863784 \rightarrow 37 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 1$
>  $1243242 \rightarrow 18 \rightarrow 9$
>  $1742 \rightarrow 16 \rightarrow 5$

Comment: But then 1863784 should evaluate to 1, no?  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Ooooops. I added the wrong numbers, it seems.

Comment: Well it worked for the last two... perhaps the question writer made the same mistake I did?

Comment: It's possible.  I was thinking step 3 had to do something extra to make it right like "r[et]urn[ e]v[i]l[answ]e[r 2 if 1]."

Comment: It appears I did make a mistake. This is indeed correct.

Comment: I just want to mention that the output is the unique whole number between 1 and 9 such that when you subtract it from the input, you get a multiple of 9.

Comment: Yep. It's known as the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root), or $x \pmod 9$ with $0$ being switched with $9$.

Answer (score 2):

This is incomplete, but I'd like to know if I'm on the right track...

Step 1

> ad[d ]al[l t]he[ n]um[be]rs

Step 2

> r[e]p[e]at[ ]st[e]p[ 1 ]u[n]t[i]l[ ]o[n]e[ ]t[????? ] s[i]n[g]le[ ]d[i]g[i]t

Step 3

> Profit

Comment: I believe you are.

Comment: I might have screwed up.  Step 1 should probably read "Collect underpants."

Comment: Nope, you were right about the first step.

Comment: Was a South Park allusion, akshully.

Comment: You're on the right track.